# Scale a Web Image in iOS

Tags: ios, image, scaling

I've managed to set my app to download an image from the web into it but the image is getting cropped. Does anyone know of a way to scale it down on-the-fly?

Comment: It might be necessary that you show the community the code that you use to download the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste your code so we can help you, paste the viewController.h and viewController.m at a minimum.

Or take a working model from a tutorial site and modify it for your needs.  Try this example I cooked up and see if it will help you http://iossentials.com/2012/04/29/building-an-ios-app-to-load-an-image-from-internet-and-resize-it-using-uiimage/